# predict_proba gives different results in similar environments

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, google-colaboratory, lightgbm

So I'm training a model(lightgbm) using Google Colab. Then I serialize model into a pickle file(*.pkl).
This file I use(read_pickle) locally in a script. For this purpose I use Spyder(Anaconda) IDE.

To validate that I get the same results I compared predict_proba results between Spyder(Anaconda) IDE and in Google Colab. And unfortunately they differ by a significant margin!

Despite that I have the same versions:

- python=3.9.13
- pandas=1.4.4
- numpy=1.21.5
- lightgbm=3.2.1
- scikit-learn=1.0.2

I use Spyder IDE because I have Windows machine and also because software which communicates with script is also Windows based. I didn't have any problems with this setup, until recently when I had to reinstall Anaconda. After which I noticed the difference.

How to achieve that predict_proba gives one and the same results in both environments?

At this point I have triple checked that I am using one and the same input data and one and the same pickle file in both environments.

When I first noticed discrepancy I equalized  python, pandas, numpy, lightgbm and scikit-learn versions and retrained model. It didn't help and predict_proba still gives different results in both environments.

Code, here is basically how I train model:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier

    #...read feature file, label file, drop some columns etc.

    Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, labelss,test_size=0.2, random_state=52, shuffle=False)

    eval_setb = [(Xtest, ytest)]

    modelb_opt = LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=110000,learning_rate=0.001,max_depth=20,
                 num_leaves=46,colsample_bytree=0.012217664054347373,
                 lambda_l1=2.0236823308340988e-07,lambda_l2=6.127039442996004e-06,
                 min_data_in_leaf=335,feature_fraction=0.7647946800740761,
                 bagging_fraction=0.46500934520303194,objective="binary", 
                 class_weight='balanced')

    modelb_opt.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, eval_set = eval_setb,early_stopping_rounds=1000, eval_metric='logloss')

    pd.to_pickle(modelb_opt, "C:/path/to/file/file_name.pkl")
```

Update:
I re-trained model locally on my PC in Spyder(Anaconda) IDE. The results of predict_proba didn't change in Spyder IDE, e.g. when reading model locally either locally trained or in Google Colab, I got the same faulty predict_proba output.

Comment: Are random seeds set? Also check BLAS/LAPACK versions. Generally, this question is too broad - can you narrow down a reproducible example?

Comment: I don't do data shuffle so random seeds are not important. blas version is the same, but mkl version does differ.

Comment: MKL is a BLAS implementation, and that might make a difference. But I’m not confident to completely assign the blame there.

Comment: You set random state for data split, but not for the classifier. Can you try setting a state for that as well?

Comment: Ok, I will do that. In the mean time, I re-trained model locally on my PC in Spyder(Anaconda) IDE. And when I compared this model predict_proba on Spyder IDE, I got the same faulty result when I read model prepared in Google Colab. So the result didn't change whether I trained model locally or in Google Colab!

Comment: How exactly did you run Python 3.9 on the Colab Notebook? AFAIK the notebook runtime cannot be changed (but you can install and use via command-line other Python instances in the same node)